# Como compartilhar uma URL ou imagem direto no Instagram?

Tags: php, javascript, api, instagram-api

Como é feito no Facebook:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo MINHA_URL;?>
```

E no Twitter:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<?php echo TEXTO.' '.MINHA_URL?>
```

Eu andei [**pesquisando nesse site**](https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/#media_redirect), mas não entendi como fazer para criar um link direto da url do site.

Também vi [**este exemplo aqui**](https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/master/modules/shortcodes/instagram.php), mas não sei como usar sem ser através do wordpress.

Também tem [**esse exemplo**](https://github.com/MichMich/Instagram-PHP-API).

Comment: Não entendi onde entra o `css`. Mas você está usando algum plugin em JS ou PHP ?

Comment: Fato. Nada a ver com css... é que eu ia publicar todo o código, mas deixei pra lá.

Comment: Veja esse: https://wordpress.org/plugins/instafeed/ Já usei, mas não em Wordpress.

Comment: Não estou usando Wordpress. Tenho uma loja feita com Prestashop e preciso colocar um botão para compartilhar o produto no instagram.

Comment: Aparentemente o que o @IvanFerrer deseja é que o usuário compartilhe uma imagem, publicando-a em seu perfil. Isso NÃO é possível através da API do Instagram. Apenas através da API Interna do Instagram, que precisará saber a chave privada do aplicativo, além disso será necessário que o usuário informe o login/senha. Poucos sãos os aplicativos de terceiros que possuem acesso a API para publicar imagens. Existe como solicitar para o usuário publicar  a imagem usando o `Mobile Sharing`, apenas. Mas isso exige que o aplicativo chame o aplicativo do Instagram para executar a ação.